# Plot DataFrame before and after outlier removal

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

linking this solved question (again thx alot @mozway and jezrael!) [Remove outlier with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479228/remove-outlier-with-python)

I would like to plot the outlier removal.
What I want: A scatter plot consisting of 7 subplots made with all rows (x-axes should be the time from the first row, the other rows should be the y-axes, respectively). The removed values should be highlighted. How can I do this?

I thought about plotting before and after the removal and insert both into a single plot.

I have two approaches to plot:

```
Ni60 = data[['60Ni']]
Ni61 = data[['61Ni']]
Ni62 = data[['62Ni']]
Cu63 = data[['63Cu']]
Ni64 = data[['64Ni']]
Cu65 = data[['65Cu']]
Zn66 = data[['66Zn']]
Time = data[['Time']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex = True, figsize = (13, 8))
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100 
fig.suptitle(basename)

ax[0, 0].scatter(Time, Ni60)
ax[0, 1].scatter(Time, Ni61)
ax[1, 0].scatter(Time, Cu63)
ax[1, 1].scatter(Time, Cu65)

for axis in ax.flat: axis.set_xlim(0, 32)
ax[0, 0].set_ylim(0, 0.02)
ax[1, 0].set_ylim(0, 0.02)
ax[0, 1].set_ylim(0, 0.002)
ax[1, 1].set_ylim(0, 0.02)


ax[0, 0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax[0, 1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax[1, 0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax[1, 1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax[0, 0].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
ax[0, 1].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
ax[1, 0].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
ax[1, 1].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')

ax[0, 0].set_title('$^{60}$Ni', color = 'b')
ax[0, 1].set_title('$^{61}$Ni', color = 'b')
ax[1, 0].set_title('$^{63}$Cu', color = 'b')
ax[1, 1].set_title('$^{65}$Cu', color = 'b')

fig.savefig(outfile + "blank.png", dpi=150)
```

and

```
f = sns.relplot(data=data.melt(id_vars='Time', value_name='Spannung (V)'), x='Time', y='Spannung (V)', col='variable', col_wrap=2, kind='line', marker='o')
f.fig.savefig("out.png")
```

But these will generate either before and/or after the outlier removal. I would like to plot the data in blue and the outlier in red.

The outlier is removed by:

```
from scipy import stats
cols = list(df.drop(columns='Time').columns)
# or
# cols = ['60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn']

df[cols] = df[cols].where(np.abs(stats.zscore(df[cols])) < 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not the best method logically, if you draw in red with the data before the outlier exclusion and then draw the outlier in blue, the outlier will not be overwritten and will remain red.

```
from scipy import stats
cols = list(df.drop(columns='Time').columns)
dfo = pd.DataFrame({'Time':df['Time']})
dfo[cols] = df[cols].mask(np.abs(stats.zscore(df[cols])) >= 2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 8), dpi=100)
fig.suptitle('Outlier graph')

for idx, (c,ax) in enumerate(zip(cols, axes.flatten())):
    ax.scatter(df['Time'], df[c], color='r')
    ax.scatter(dfo['Time'], dfo[c], color='b')    
    ax.set(xlim=(0,32), ylim=(0,0.01))
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
    ax.set_title('${}${}'.format(c[:2], c[2:]), color='b')

#fig.savefig(outfile + "blank.png", dpi=150)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To read in a data file and create a graph

```
for c in cols:
    data = pd.read_csv(c+'.csv', ...)
    for ax in axes.flatten():
    ...
    fig.savefig(c+'_blank.png',dpi=150)
```

Comment: is it possible to do this for every column? I mean to make a plot with 7 subplots.

Comment: `plt.subplots(4, 2,...)` Just change it.

Comment: and can I use different ylim for each subplot?

Comment: The y-axis can be removed from the loop process and set individually.

Comment: Eight graphs will be generated, but use this to hide the last graph. `axes.flat[-1].set_visible(False)`

Comment: It did, thank you very much :-) I flagged it as the correct answer :-) One more question: this plotting function is a module which is called by another function to do this for every file in a specific folder. How can I save each plot for each input file with the inputs filename? Right now it will get overwritten by the next plot.

Comment: You could add a new loop process to the file saving code and save it as a file name from the file name list.